# Flex-grow seems to not adjusting height of elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want a second element `app-item` in parent element `app` to grow in height while there is free space so the footer will be always at the bottom of the website. But it seems that *flex-grow: 1;* is not working. How should I make it work. On my other projects it is working as I expected but here I can't find reason why it is not.

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.app{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.app-item:nth-child(1){
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #fdd;
}

.app-item:nth-child(2){
    order: 0;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #dfd;
}

.app-item:nth-child(3){
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
        
        <div class="app-item">
            <nav class="app-item navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QuoraASoL</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Logout</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Create Question</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
        <div id="main-area" class="app-item">
            Content block
        </div>

        <div class="app-item">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" id="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Adventure Side of Life</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.app` container is as high as its content, so there is no space for content elements to grow.

To make the `.app` container as high as the body, you could specify the height of the `body` with a minimum of the full window height (`height: 100%; min-height: 100vh;`), and make the `.app` as high as the body (`height: 100%;`).

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.app{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.app-item:nth-child(1){
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #fdd;
}

.app-item:nth-child(2){
    order: 0;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #dfd;
}

.app-item:nth-child(3){
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
        
        <div class="app-item">
            <nav class="app-item navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QuoraASoL</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Logout</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Create Question</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
        <div id="main-area" class="app-item">
            Content block
        </div>

        <div class="app-item">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" id="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Adventure Side of Life</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting ```app``` 's height: 100%; did not change anything.  ```.app```'s height remained  as high as content.

Comment: Did you also try with adding `height: 100%; min-height: 100vh;` on `body`?

Comment: Yes the body height is set on 100%.

Comment: And with `min-height: 100vh`?

Comment: Yeah the ```body``` is spread out through full height.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is your exact code but there is a code snippet in my answer with nearly the code you provided. You can display the rendered HTML/CSS by clicking on "Run code snippet". In that code the 3 rules I told you are enough to make it work. If it's too small you can click on "Full page" to see the result in full screen.

Comment: Okay, thanks for help. Nice suddenly it is working :) :)